# When I set angularjs directive templateUrl $rootScope event does not populate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two directive that one of them broadcast a message to get another one like this: ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/3082/))

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').directive('foo', 
    function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
           $rootScope.$on("onStart", function(e,d){
                alert(d.message)
           });
        }
      };
    }
  );
angular.module('app').directive('bar',
    function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',      
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("onStart", {message: "start"});
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

This gieves the message.

But I need template url of my directive and set it like this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/3083/)).

```
  angular.module('app').directive('foo', 
    function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        templateUrl: "tpl.html",
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
           $rootScope.$on("onStart", function(e,d){
                alert(d.message)
           });
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

But it does not populate the alert now.

Answer (score 0):

For the `link` function to be executed, Angular needs the template. But the template is now loaded from an html file asynchronously. Hence your message broadcasts before the link function in the first directive is even executed and thus before the listener in the rootScope is created.

Comment: is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: This seems wrong for me, but you could just place the registration of your `onStart` listener before the return statement of the `foo` directive. It works but is very hacky, plus it does not give you access to all the params that angular passes to the `link` function.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to use `template` instead of `templateUrl`

```
 template: "<div>Content of the template.</div>"
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/3102/)

Comment: but templates have very long content. directive controller works before link function. but it does not populate as wel.